# what is the difference between $this->attributes and $this->original

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I put a breakpoint inside a function in my model in Laravel 4.

I see on `$this` there is both **attributes** and **original**.

Both seem to contain the same data, i.e. a key/value pair representing fields in the table.

What's the difference?

I need a function in my model that will return all the fields as an associative array, which one do I use?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have the same data until you change any of your attributes:

```
$user->name = "user391986";
```

Then you'll have

```
$user->attributes['name'] != $user->original['name'];
```